# Condition based font-family selection on availability

Tags: html, css

I would like to write css or some thing that it will make font-family dynamic like on user side if user has Helvetica text available then font-family will be Helvetica if not then font-family will be Arial, How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way is to add them all (most specific to most generic) as a comma delimited list in your style rule.  If the first one is unavailable, the second is used, and if not that one, the third, etc.

```
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```